# What is the easiest, no-frills way to produce a simple video on Windows 10?

Tags: video-recording, windows

This question is basically the same as one I posted 2.5 years ago [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/10309/what-is-the-easiest-no-frills-way-to-produce-a-simple-video-on-windows-8), except that now I am using a different laptop that runs Windows 10 instead of Windows 8.

My laptop has a camera. Since it can obviously take video of me (a la Skyping), it should be easy to create a video of myself practicing a presentation.

My laptop runs Windows 10.

This is going to be a long video -- 1.5 hours. What is the easiest way to accomplish that using apps that come with Windows or something free that I can download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into using [OBS (Open Broadcaster Software)](https://obsproject.com/). It's free, and allows you to capture from a webcam and/or your actual monitors or windows. Many people use it for streaming to sites like [Twitch](https://twitch.tv), but it also has built-in options for recording to a file.

Comment: I wanted to do nearly the same thing on my Windows 7 laptop. I needed to make a 2 minute video of a device I built.  I messed around for a day with Camtasia, only to find out this very feature-rich video editor couldn't do this "simple" recording task. I ended up using Debut Video Capture Software. Free download. Got it working in 5 minutes to do exactly what I needed. I don't know if it works for Windows 10.